# Please guide me why NE555 is burning

Tags: mosfet, 555

I use an NE555 to drive 2 n-channel MOSFETs.

After working a few times, the NE555 burns.

Where is the problem in my circuit?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked whether 5V is sufficient supply voltage for your ne555? And: is it high enough to actually drive the MOSFET? Generally: don't use the ne555; if you rally need its functionality, use the CMOS 555 variants instead; they're lower in supply needs. This is not the 1960s!

Comment: Also note that this looks like some push/pull square wave generator; something that is much easier to build with a cheap modern microcontroller, who, as a bonus, also has a dead time protection.

Comment: I think your control voltage capacitor on pin 5 should go to GND. But that should not cause it to "burn". You probably have the connector going to a center tapped transformer and inductive transients are getting back to the 5V Vcc. Also the ON times of the MOSFETs are probably not equal. Please show your entire circuit.

Comment: Are you sure that AMS1117 is stable ? It requires a tantalum cap on the output for stability reasons according to the datasheet. If it's oscillating all bets are off.

Comment: When R6 is set to zero, C2 will discharge into U1 pin 7 with high current. Add a resistor in series with R6.

Comment: I second what Paul says. Give some details about the load i.e. what the MOSFETs are driving. Did you observe the waveforms of MOSFET drains when loaded and unloaded? If the two MOSFETs are supposed to form a push-pull driver then there should be a dead time between them (the inverter formed with T1 will bring no dead time) because everything can happen without a dead time.

Comment: I have only connect 12V 1A lamp to each channel. The circuit has no other part.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have found some CMOS 555s more fragile driving heavy loads ( another highly capacitive load - charge pump) than the old bipolar ones.

Comment: hm, you're right, but that really depends on the load, though. Generally, the CMOS variants have lower rds_on, so there's less thermal problems.